# My question makes no sense; what do I do?

Tags: discussion

I have concluded that one of my questions ([Compactness for definable models?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288621/compactness-for-definable-models)) does not make sense, and isn't worth trying to answer. What is the appropriate way to proceed in this kind of situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The philosophy of SE is that comments are somewhat transient elements of the site, not meant to preserve information for the long term. Since your answer received enlightening comments that made an answer unnecessary,  it is reasonable to copy them into a community-wiki answer, with attribution to the authors of the comments. Then the question will have a visible answer and the effort of the commenters will not be wasted.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I think I will do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't think there's anything to be salvaged, then you can always delete the question.

Comment: I would be amenable to that. My only concern is that I don't wish to delete the comments that were made on the question, some of which I thought were enlightening. Do I have other options?

Comment: @NickThomas, Well as what 5PM said perhaps you could write an answer mark it community wiki and summarize the comments explaining why the question is "bad".

Comment: I think the obvious question to consider is the one you asked, but without parameters being allowed. It seems interesting.

Comment: Andres: That's a good point; it certainly could be interesting! I've added this to the question.